# Why does this thread never gets declared or started?

Tags: multithreading, python-3.x, producer-consumer

I'm implementing an image downloader with the producer-consumer model. One thread is responsible for generating **(url, filename)** pairs and put them in queue. I want MAX_THREADS threads to pick the pairs and start downloading. Here are my threads:

```
class Extractor(Thread):
    def __init__(self, group=None, target=None, name=None,
                 args=(), kwargs=None, verbose=None, items=None):
        super(Extractor, self).__init__()
        self.target = target
        self.name = name
        self.items = items

    def run(self):
        while True:
            for item in self.items:
                if not QUEUE.full():
                    QUEUE.put_nowait(extract(item))
                    logging.debug('Putting ' + str(item) + ' : ' + str(QUEUE.qsize()) + ' items in queue')

class Downloader(Thread):
    def __init__(self, group=None, target=None, name=None,
                 args=(), kwargs=None, verbose=None):
        super(Downloader, self).__init__()
        self.target = target
        self.name = name
        self.seen = set()

    def run(self):
        while True:
            if not QUEUE.empty():
                pair = QUEUE.get_nowait()
                # I have seen the URL
                if pair[0] in self.seen:
                    continue
                else:
                    # Never seen it before
                    self.seen.add(pair[0])
                    logging.debug('Downloading ' + str(pair[1]) + ' : ' + str(QUEUE.qsize()) + ' items in queue')
                    download_one_pic(pair)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    items = None
    items = crawl('username__', items)
    worker_threads = []

    producer = Extractor(name='Extractor', items=items)
    producer.daemon = True
    producer.start()

    consumer = Downloader(name='Downloader[1]')
    consumer2 = Downloader(name='Downloader[2]')
    worker_threads.append(consumer)
    worker_threads.append(consumer2)

    for thread in worker_threads:
        thread.start()
        thread.join()
```

The **queue** has the max size of 50 and I want **Producer** thread to run regardless of other threads so I have it **demonized**. One thing is weird is that the **consumer2** thread never gets started and I don't have any idea why. As in my log, only `Downloader[1]` does the job and the queue keeps fluctuating between 49 and 50 so I knew that the `Downloader[2]` never gets started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling join() on a thread waits until it is complete before it returns. That loop at the end of your code will only ever execute once because the Downloader classes loop forever. Call start in one loop and then loop over them again to join() and wait there after all threads have been started